# Index Error, out of range Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have created connect 4; it is a 7 by 6 grid. Below is an algorithm to test whether a diagonal connect 4 has won. Although, when the chips are in the positions shown in the image, an index error occurs. How do I fix this, and how do I get the diagonal algorithms to work?

[image]

```
board[5][1] = 1 # (red chip)

board[4][2] = 1 # (red chip)

board[3][3] = 1 # (red chip) #THIS IS WHEN ERROR OCCURS FOR THE FIRST DIAGONAL ALGORITHM

# check / diagonal spaces
for x in range(7 - 3):
    for y in range(3, 6):
        if board[x][y] == 1  and board[x+1][y-1] == 1 and board[x+2][y-2] == 1 and board[x+3][y-3] == 1:
            return True

# check \ diagonal spaces
for x in range(7 - 3):
    for y in range(6 - 3):
        if board[x][y] == 1 and board[x+1][y+1] == 1 and board[x+2][y+2] == 1 and board[x+3][y+3] == 1:
            return True
```

Error:

```
 if board[x][y] == 1  and board[x+1][y-1] == 1 and board[x+2][y-2] == 1 and board[x+3][y-3] == 1:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `range(7 - 3)` is the same as `range(4)`, which will count from 0 to 3.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Well its the only way I thought which would allow me to detect a diagonal connect 4 but I may have confused the maths of this. Which could be the reason diagonal wins aren't being detected.

Answer (score 1):

Since the board has 6 rows (0 -> 5), and you starting `x` from row 3 (0-based index) so `board[x+3][y-3]` will give `list index out of range` because x+3 = 6 > 5.

Answer (score 0):

You're numbering your rows from 1 to 7 instead of 0 to 6.

Also, the loop you're doing should use a comma, not a hyphen.

```
    for x in range (4, 7): # This will count 4, 5, 6
```

If you use a hyphen, the computer will do subtraction. You end up with

```
    for x in range (7 - 3): # Computer will do subtraction, this will count 0, 1, 2, 3
```

Also, you're going to need a more general algorithm for checking diagonals. You'll need to use variables, not numbers. As a tip, I check the vertical/horizontal/diagonal only from where the last piece was placed each move.

Comment: didnt seem to work, still go index errors when I changed it