# IndexError: list index out of range - surdsk

Tags: python, python-3.x

sorry i am new to python
any idea why its ending with error/ how to fix it?:

> if surdsk[20]>5:

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def rectangle():
    for i in range(1):
        canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20, 20+20, 20+30, fill='red')

def MoveLeft(action):
    surdsk=canvas.coords(rectangle)
    if surdsk[20]>5:
        canvas.move(rectangle,-10,0)

        
canvas = Canvas()
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind_all('<Key-Left>', MoveLeft)
rectangle()
```

Comment: It's ending with an error because list index is out of range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index Error, out of range Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427552/index-error-out-of-range-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You seem to be confusing the rectangle canvas element and the function that creates it. `rectangle`, in your `MoveLeft` function, is not the rectangle you created, but really the procedure `rectangle()`. This procedure has no canvas coords, therefore 1) `surdsk` is an empty list, which doesn't contain a 20th element (hence the IndexError), and 2) you can't obviously move it. In your `rectangle` function, you should save the return value of `create_rectangle` and use it in `MoveLeft`.
- A rectangle element has 4 coordinates (top-left X, top-left Y, bottom-right X, bottom-right Y), not 20. Even if the above would be fixed, `surdsk[20]` would still raise an exception.

Now, sorry to be so direct, but I have the impression you don't really understand the code you wrote or copied from some source. For example, could you explain the purpose of `for i in range(1):` ?
If you are new to python, or to computer programming in general, you should consider writing a couple of console-only scripts, following an entry-level tutorial, to get some basic understanding of the language fetures, before moving to graphical library (even if tkinter is no really rocket science).